# 'no definition found' in vscode with python extension in vscode, when injecting module

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

When i inject my a module as parameter and i want to look it up in vscode with CTRL+ mousclick, it says 'no definition found'

for example:

```
db.py
-----
def get data():
    # getting data

main.py
-------
import db
def start(db):
    mymodule.execute(db)

mymodule.py
----------
def execute(db):
   db.get_data()
```

If i click here on get_data() with **CTRL + mouseclick**, it cannot find the definition. Is that due to python and because it is dynamically typed?

Comment: Based on the content of `mymodule.py`, how should intellisense know what `db` is?

Comment: I updated it. db gets imported in main.py

Comment: now db is also an argument for `start` so no info what it might be, and nothing happens in `main`. And still no info in `mymodule.py` on what `db` is. Intellisense does not look over py files to see what it might be if you don't give it a path. Use imports.